# Can tomcat instance serve http and https pages

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https

My website is runs on Tomcat 70.0.30 and Apache, all the pages are jsp so I think almost everything actually go to tomcat. I currently only support payments with Paypal. I want to add Credit Card payments, Stripe seems like a good bet, but requires the pages to use Https.

So if I purchase an SSL Certificate for now can I just convert he payment pages to https and leave the rest as http, or does that make no sense. Can tomcat intance support both.

My main domain is http://www.jthink.net underneath we have
http://www.jthink.net/songkong
http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz

We also have domains such as http://songkong.net which redirects to http://www.jthink.net/songkong  using Amazon S3 buckets with a redirect. We also have none www urls such as http://jthink.net which redirects to http://www.jthink.net. I think this is done on the server that hosts www.jthink.net. Does any of this affect the type of SSL certificate purchased.

If I change my http pages to redirect to https pages does this affect Google rankings in any negative way.

Comment: You should serve everything as HTTPS.

Comment: You can use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Thanks so I dont need to purchase a certifciate, are there disavnatges with this approach. I know in long run I shoud move to https but would be more manageable if I didnt have to do it all in one go.

Comment: if I serve all as https, then what happens to the http page. i,e if that page no longer exists because now served as http page what happens if user enters the http page ?

Comment: You need to make it redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: So if the current page is now served as https - page1.jsp where do i configure that http - page1.jsp   now redirects to https - page1.jsp. This would not seem to be in tomcat itself would it because tomcat not serving such pages, do I do it as part of Amazon S3 config or within Apache (i have never had to configure anything in Apache upto this point)